# Can I use a 5v xtal osc with a 3v MCU? Will a simple npn buffer work?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, oscillator

I have several crystal oscillator cans that run on 5v. I have a PIC24HJ128 on a breadboard. The PIC uses 3v. I want to use a simple npn transistor to buffer the osc out into the CLK in. Will this work? Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: It depends on your clock frequency, the type of oscillator being used, what sort of signal the pic expects on its clock pin, and that's just what I could think of immediately. Please provide more details if you want useful answers.

Comment: You don't actually need gain; it's likely that with correct design you could use a resistive divider, but you'd likely need to tune it to the loading of the input.  You may actually need fairly little signal level into the MCU input, so over-reducing may be fine.  Hopefully this is a non-critical bench project.

Comment: Just make a voltage divider of 2 series resistors, each being 10,000 ohms. The time constant --- 5Kohm and 5pF --- is 25 nanosecond, or about 7MHz F3dB. If you want faster frequencies, drop the resistor values inversely.

Comment: I am using a 4MHz oscillator. 10ns rise time, 15pF, 10 TTL load. I thought an emitter follower with collector at 3v would prevent over-voltage on the CLK input. I'll try the voltage divider first. Thanks for your help.

Comment: An emitter follower would still need a healthy pull-down, and it'd only reduce the voltage to 4.3V.  I'd use a resistive divider, scaled for the speed of the clock, the rise & fall times specified for the micro, and the anticipated input capacitance of the micro (a nice conservative number for which is 10pF -- if you can make it work there without the resistor values being too low, then you can probably just stop and call it good).

Comment: Simple solution: buy the correct oscillator instead, for a few dollars.

Comment: Ooops! I looked up an open-collector buffer and saw it is a common emitter configuration. The collector resistor goes to the other voltage. As for this being a duplicate of another question, there is one difference; I have both voltage rails available: 5V for the oscillator and 3V for the PIC. I'm trying to avoid using up an 8-bit level translator chip when I only need to translate 1 line. And it is a bench project on a breadboard, so no critical functions will be harmed in the event of smoke.

Answer (score 0):

1.1K/1.3K should work well. Vih is 0.7Vdd and Vil is 0.2Vdd for OSC input, so 
2.1V and 0.6V assuming a 3.0V nominal PIC Vdd.

Here's what the waveform would look like with a 10pF load assuming a 35 ohm drive resistance from the oscillator. There is a nominal ~600mV
of noise margin on either side and the rise and fall times are not too terrible.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWOPks.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]